# How To Get Simple Product Name From Configurable Product From Ordered Product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, simple-product

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item
{

   $orderItemId = $item->getOrderItemId();

   $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load($orderItemId);

   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

   $html.='<tr height="10">
     <td>'.$item->getSku().'</td>

     <td colspan="3">'.$product->getName().'</td>

     <td>'.(int)$orderItem->getQtyBackordered().'</td>

     <td>'.(int)$item['qty_ordered'].'</td>

   </tr>';
}
```

With this code i am getting both simple and configurable product name but when i replace **getAllItems** by **getAllVisibleItems** then only show configurable product name but i want to show simple product name which was order

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer,

```
foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $childItems = $item->getChildrenItems();
    foreach($item->getChildrenItems() as $item){
       echo $item->getProduct()->getName(); // child product Name
     }
}
```